# Is it possible to simulate or replicate a cryptographic algorithm using Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I would like to know if it is possible to recreate or simulate a cryptographic encryption algorithm like DES or AES using the quantum computing platform Qiskit from IBM?

Comment: The quantum cloud computing platform (having access to real quantum chips) by IBM is named IBM Quantum Experience. Qiskit is a Python module which helps to interface with the IBM Q backend or a simulator. And of course, you can implement any quantum algorithm using Qiskit, although whether there are already examples out there is the real question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes. It is possible. Sanchayn gave a good answer.

Long answer: Also yes, but it may not work well or be computationally effective. It appears that AES and DES are both cryptographic algorithms used currently in a fully classical setting. As the `[quantum gates][1]` implemented in the IBM Q systems are computationally (Also known as functionally) complete (can compute any algorithm given enough time and qbits) it follows they can do it.
But they may not be able to do it well. Just like (and even more so) there are things a CPU can do better than a GPU, and vice versa, there are things a classical computer can do better than a quantum computer. Recreating or simulating these algorithms may be one thing a classical computer does better.
It could be that nobody has done it because our current computers are too small or noisy, or it could just be that it's not worth doing it since a classical computer does so much better at it anyway. I have not seen any.

A common, related question that simulating or recreating an encryption algorithm may help with is if IBM Q systems can break AES or DES (probably using Shor's algorithm). That would be no, we need more Qubits and fault-tolerance. I'm not seeing AES or DES specifically, but `[RSA probably needs a minimum of 10k][2]` and would still have a running time of 10 days with current Quantum processor speeds.

If we guess that we need roughly the same number of Qubits to simulate as to break, then the answer is no, but it is theoretically possible.